# How to export Google Analytics data to a Google GCS bucket or to BigQuery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataprep

Is there a way to export Google Analytics data to a Google GCS bucket or to BigQuery? I'm trying to use Google Dataprep to have a better look over data from analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export to BigQuery is available only with Analytics 360 subscription (paid). [Source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618?hl=en). The exact integration process is described [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092).

Comment: https://www.scitylana.com can extract full historical data at a hit level basis. This means no sampling and all the hits sent to your GA properties since "beginning of time". It's a paid service, but MUCH cheaper than GA360 if you only need the data in BigQuery. Data is delivered in BigQuery in a partitioned table. The table contains up to 100 dimensions and metrics. The extraction is done via the API. This means all dimensions are the exact same as in GA. This is a winner if you have other people involved. Same taxonomy and interpretation.